# Plotting Standard Errors for a Matrix(with replicate data)

Tags: r, matrix, bar-chart, standard-error

There have been many discussions on plotting error bars in R and often many solutions.
I was wondering, if this would be possible to do for a matrix data with replicates.

For example:

```
dataset <- read.table(text="Cond1.Rep1 Cond1.Rep2 Cond1.Rep3   Cond2.Rep1    Cond2.Rep2    Cond2.Rep3
4   6   10  10  6   4
5   7   5   10  4   5
4   8   4   2   4   2
6   4   8   5   3   3
7   5   8   6   4   5
7   5   8   8   7   5
8   5   9   9   8   5
4   5   4   3   8   7
6   6   4   5   4   2
4   6   7   7   8   3", head=TRUE)
```

Somthing like computing another matrix that would give the values for Standard Error based on groups ("Cond1" and "Cond2"). Any quick possibilities, so we can generate plots for any row in a matrix (or perhaps even all the rows)?

Thanks

Comment: The standard error of what?

Comment: of replicates for each condition.

Comment: Is your question 'how to calc std error' or 'how to plot all rows/cols of a matrix?  For the latter, see `?matplot

Comment: something like matplot but with standard error!!... solution below seems to be fine!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should reshape your data first:

```
library(reshape2)
dat <- melt(dataset)
dat <- cbind(dat, 
             do.call(rbind, strsplit(as.character(dat$variable), ".", fixed=TRUE)))
names(dat)[3:4] <- c("Cond", "Rep")
dat$sample <- seq_len(nrow(dataset))

aggregate(value~sample+Cond, data=dat, FUN=function(x) sd(x)/sqrt(length(x)))
#    sample  Cond     value
# 1       1 Cond1 1.7638342
# 2       2 Cond1 0.6666667
# 3       3 Cond1 1.3333333
# 4       4 Cond1 1.1547005
# 5       5 Cond1 0.8819171
# 6       6 Cond1 0.8819171
# 7       7 Cond1 1.2018504
# 8       8 Cond1 0.3333333
# 9       9 Cond1 0.6666667
# 10     10 Cond1 0.8819171
# 11      1 Cond2 1.7638342
# 12      2 Cond2 1.8559215
# 13      3 Cond2 0.6666667
# 14      4 Cond2 0.6666667
# 15      5 Cond2 0.5773503
# 16      6 Cond2 0.8819171
# 17      7 Cond2 1.2018504
# 18      8 Cond2 1.5275252
# 19      9 Cond2 0.8819171

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(dat, aes(x=factor(sample), y=value, colour=Cond)) + 
  stat_summary(fun.data=mean_sdl, mult=1/sqrt(3))
```

[image]

Comment: This is perfect, would be great if we could plot them next to each other (instead of combining conditions, like in this plot) as barplots.. I shall give that a try though!

Comment: That's just a matter of how you do this with ggplot2. It's quite easy.